# npm- module not recognized even though it's installed

Tags: node.js, npm

I am running on windows.

My module is install via `npm install`. It's located in the `node_modules` which was locally created at my project.

For some reason, all of a sudden `node` has stop recognizing my module, even though it is installed and located in the `root/node_modules` location!!

I have tried every thing I could find online. What is going on???

- tried clearing npm's cache
- kill node.js process
- re-open my command-line
- even restarted my PC!!
- path is configured correctly

One more thing:

if i manually install the package via: `npm install --save my-module`
its recognizing my package.

**EDIT**

I have noticed that when I run `npm install` it does not create the `node_modules/.bin` folder as of when I run `npm install --save my-module` it does create it.

**EDIT 2**

When manually placing my packages in the `.bin` folder than it works

Comment: can you see if it works with yarn ? I have noticed that npm goes wack on windows.

Comment: What's the module and how are you requiring it? Some modules (`moment` for example) have problems that the index files are not properly recognised so you have to required them like `require('moment/moment')`)

Comment: @Raul Rene every module, for example 'npm-run-all' is used in the package.json. and also 'rimraf' I am using in the package.json start configuration

Answer (score 0):

Note, that you can also execute an installed npm module using the [npx](https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/the-npx-nodejs-package-runner) (Node.js Package Runner), which is part of npm.

`npx my-module`

You should see the module executable in `./node_modules/.bin`

Answer (score -1):

> Please, at first re-install your node and shutdown your PC for 5 at least mins.

### You can follow the following steps:

- Search *environment variables* from start menu's search box.
- Click it then go to *Environment Variables*
- Click **PATH**
- click **Edit**
- Click **New** and try to *copy* and *paste* your path for '*bin*' folder [find where you installed the node] for example according to my machine '`C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin`'

#### If you got any error. try the another step:

- Click **New**, then browse for the '*bin*' folder

Comment: there's no need to "re-install your node and shutdown your PC for 5 at least mins"